# Concat two strings in mySQL : Illegal mix of collations

Tags: mysql, string, casting, character, concatenation

I know that's maybe a very simple question, but i have this error :

> Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and
>   (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation 'like'

Here is my mySQL code :

```
SET @var1 = YEAR(CURDATE())-11; 
SET @var2 = CAST(@var1 AS CHAR);
SET @var3 = CONCAT("%", @var2, "%");


DELETE a,b,c,d
FROM wp_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships b ON ( a.ID = b.object_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c ON ( a.ID = c.post_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy d ON ( d.term_taxonomy_id = b.term_taxonomy_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_terms e ON ( e.term_id = d.term_id )
WHERE e.slug LIKE @var3;
```

I start to use `CONCAT` and `CAST` so maybe i did something wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Why using variables for this? `WHERE slug LIKE CONCAT("%", YEAR(CURDATE())-11, "%")` or remove the CAST to CHAR

Comment: It was just an example, but your answer works for me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.slug` is declared to be `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, but `@var3` is `utf8mb4_general_ci`. You need to convert them to the same collation before comparing.

```
SET @var3 = CONVERT(CONCAT("%", @var2, "%") USING utf8mb4_unicode_ci);
```